# How to generate rows based on a constrain of values from a column?

Tags: postgresql

So far, I am using this Query:

```
SELECT "FailCode", 
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =10 or "FailCode"=14 or "FailCode"=18 or "FailCode"=23 or "FailCode"=27 or "FailCode"=35 or "FailCode"=40) as "Ch1",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =11 or "FailCode"=15 or "FailCode"=19 or "FailCode"=24 or "FailCode"=28 or "FailCode"=36 or "FailCode"=41) as "Ch2",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =12 or "FailCode"=16 or "FailCode"=20 or "FailCode"=25 or "FailCode"=29 or "FailCode"=37 or "FailCode"=42) as "Ch3",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =13 or "FailCode"=17 or "FailCode"=21 or "FailCode"=26 or "FailCode"=30 or "FailCode"=38 or "FailCode"=43) as "Ch4"
FROM public.minical01
group by 1
order BY 1;
```

Which gives me these results [image]

But what I am seeking to generate a new column ("new_column") with 7 rows (as a new integer for every new row 1,2..6,7) from a range of integers from the first column "FailCode" without displaying the "FailCode" column... and instead I want to display only the "new_column" and the "Ch1", "Ch2", "Ch3", "Ch4" columns.

Every row (as integer) for the "new_column" should represent the following ranges:

1. (WHERE "FailCode" >= 10 and "FailCode" <= 13) as 1
2. (WHERE "FailCode" >= 14 and "FailCode" <= 17) as 2
3. (WHERE "FailCode" >= 18 and "FailCode" <= 21) as 3
4. (WHERE "FailCode" >= 23 and "FailCode" <= 26) as 4
5. (WHERE "FailCode" >= 27 and "FailCode" <= 30) as 5
6. (WHERE "FailCode" >= 35 and "FailCode" <= 38) as 6
7. (WHERE "FailCode" >= 40 and "FailCode" <= 43) as 7

Any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`CASE` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).  Because of the aggregation the `CASE` switch has to run in an outer query, but that lets us rearrange columns as needed:

[Demonstration fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FS-HJzpt)

```
select
  "Ch1",
  "Ch2",
  "Ch3",
  "Ch4",
  CASE WHEN "FailCode" >= 10 and "FailCode" <= 13 THEN 1
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 14 and "FailCode" <= 17 THEN 2
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 18 and "FailCode" <= 21 THEN 3
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 23 and "FailCode" <= 26 THEN 4
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 27 and "FailCode" <= 30 THEN 5
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 35 and "FailCode" <= 38 THEN 6
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 40 and "FailCode" <= 43 THEN 7
   END AS new_column
from (
SELECT "FailCode", 
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =10 or "FailCode"=14 or "FailCode"=18 or "FailCode"=23 or "FailCode"=27 or "FailCode"=35 or "FailCode"=40) as "Ch1",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =11 or "FailCode"=15 or "FailCode"=19 or "FailCode"=24 or "FailCode"=28 or "FailCode"=36 or "FailCode"=41) as "Ch2",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =12 or "FailCode"=16 or "FailCode"=20 or "FailCode"=25 or "FailCode"=29 or "FailCode"=37 or "FailCode"=42) as "Ch3",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =13 or "FailCode"=17 or "FailCode"=21 or "FailCode"=26 or "FailCode"=30 or "FailCode"=38 or "FailCode"=43) as "Ch4"
FROM public.minical01
group by 1
order BY 1
) t
```

Result table (the count results are not accurate, but will demonstrate how the new column gets added):

| Ch1 | Ch2 | Ch3 | Ch4 | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 |

### Update

To aggregate the data as you've requested, sum the **Ch** columns and `GROUP BY` our new column:

```
select
  sum("Ch1") AS "Ch1",
  sum("Ch2") AS "Ch2",
  sum("Ch3") AS "Ch3",
  sum("Ch4") AS "Ch4",
  CASE WHEN "FailCode" >= 10 and "FailCode" <= 13 THEN 1
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 14 and "FailCode" <= 17 THEN 2
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 18 and "FailCode" <= 21 THEN 3
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 23 and "FailCode" <= 26 THEN 4
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 27 and "FailCode" <= 30 THEN 5
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 35 and "FailCode" <= 38 THEN 6
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 40 and "FailCode" <= 43 THEN 7
   END AS new_column
from (
SELECT "FailCode", 
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =10 or "FailCode"=14 or "FailCode"=18 or "FailCode"=23 or "FailCode"=27 or "FailCode"=35 or "FailCode"=40) as "Ch1",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =11 or "FailCode"=15 or "FailCode"=19 or "FailCode"=24 or "FailCode"=28 or "FailCode"=36 or "FailCode"=41) as "Ch2",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =12 or "FailCode"=16 or "FailCode"=20 or "FailCode"=25 or "FailCode"=29 or "FailCode"=37 or "FailCode"=42) as "Ch3",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =13 or "FailCode"=17 or "FailCode"=21 or "FailCode"=26 or "FailCode"=30 or "FailCode"=38 or "FailCode"=43) as "Ch4"
FROM minical01
group by 1
) t
where "FailCode" between 10 and 43
group by 5
order by 5
```

| Ch1 | Ch2 | Ch3 | Ch4 | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yRAsTaT0)

Comment: Thanks, @dwhitemv. It's so close to what I am looking for. However, I get a null value for one of the new_column rows, so how can I get rid of this row with a null value? This is what I have so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIi6l.png) Also, based on these new results, this is I am trying to achieve, a table that looks which adds what I have on each channel for every item number: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agxBR.png In short, the results I am looking for should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWULD.png

Comment: Please edit your question and add this new information. NULL happens if the FailCode is out of range; what value do you want displayed then?

Comment: To achieve the new desired result you just need to `SUM` each channel column and `GROUP BY` the new column.

Comment: I have updated the answer to incorporate the new information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help. One more question. How do you get rid of the Null character (which creates its row) from the "new_column" ?

Comment: @LaloQuera NULL happens if the FailCode is out of range; what value do you want displayed then?

Comment: Thanks. what I am seeking to display is that if I get a NULL, I would not like to display it. I don't think I can set the "new_column" as not null.

Comment: I updated the update and the fiddle to only include FailCodes in bounds.  That should get rid of the NULL result if all of the channels are 0.

Comment: Hey, @dwhitemv that did not get rid of the NULL row value and its row. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Are there any FailCodes in the table less than 10 or larger than 43?

Comment: No. There are no FailCodes out of that range. But this is what I did and it works for me. Right before  END AS new_column,   and after this line "WHEN "FailCode" >= 40 and "FailCode" <= 43 THEN 7"   I added this line  ELSE 7 /*all other values, including null*/

Comment: Hey @dwhitemv, excuse my ignorance what is the "t" in: group by 1
) t

Comment: It is the required table alias for the subquery. Pretend there is an `AS` in front of it.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me so far:

```
select
  sum("Ch1") AS "Ch1",
  sum("Ch2") AS "Ch2",
  sum("Ch3") AS "Ch3",
  sum("Ch4") AS "Ch4",
  CASE WHEN "FailCode" >= 10 and "FailCode" <= 13 THEN 1
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 14 and "FailCode" <= 17 THEN 2
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 18 and "FailCode" <= 21 THEN 3
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 23 and "FailCode" <= 26 THEN 4
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 27 and "FailCode" <= 30 THEN 5
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 35 and "FailCode" <= 38 THEN 6
       WHEN "FailCode" >= 40 and "FailCode" <= 43 THEN 7
       ELSE 7 /*all other values, including null*/
  END AS new_column
from (
SELECT "FailCode",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =10 or "FailCode"=14 or "FailCode"=18 or "FailCode"=23 or "FailCode"=27 or "FailCode"=35 or "FailCode"=40) as "Ch1",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =11 or "FailCode"=15 or "FailCode"=19 or "FailCode"=24 or "FailCode"=28 or "FailCode"=36 or "FailCode"=41) as "Ch2",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =12 or "FailCode"=16 or "FailCode"=20 or "FailCode"=25 or "FailCode"=29 or "FailCode"=37 or "FailCode"=42) as "Ch3",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =13 or "FailCode"=17 or "FailCode"=21 or "FailCode"=26 or "FailCode"=30 or "FailCode"=38 or "FailCode"=43) as "Ch4"
FROM minical01
where ("FailCode" between 10 and 43) and not ("FailCode" between 31 and 34) and t_stamp >= '2022-12-8 6:00:00.000' AND t_stamp <= '2022-12-8 12:00:00.000'    
group by 1
order by 1 
) t
where t is not null 
group by 5
order by 5
```